# WPF datagrid new row not getting bound to collection

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, observablecollection

This is my datagrid

```
 <DataGrid  Name="dgItems"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding BillItems}"  >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Label Content="{DynamicResource itemcodehdr}"></Label>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate> 
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ItemCode, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Label Content="{DynamicResource itemnamehdr}"></Label>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ItemName, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                               <EventSetter Event="PreviewKeyDown"  Handler="dgItems_PreviewKeyDown"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    </DataGrid>

 Private _billItems As ObservableCollection(Of StockAccountPE)
Public Property BillItems() As ObservableCollection(Of StockAccountPE)
    Get
        Return _billItems
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of StockAccountPE))
        _billItems = value
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("BillItems"))
    End Set
End Property
```

When the window first loads my collection is empty.
After I did the below, I am getting a row in the grid

```
  _billItems = New ObservableCollection(Of StockAccountPE)
  _billItems.Add(New StockAccountPE)
_billItems.RemoveAt(0)
 BillItems = _billItems
```

After entering some value into the grid, the collection is still empty. Basically the new row in the datagrid is not getting added to the collection. This is my first issue.

The second issue is how can I raise the PropertyChanged event when an item is added to the collection. Right now it is raised when the collection is assigned some value, not when it is modified.

Comment: INPC Will happen when items are added/removed from your collection. It appears you are adding and removing items before the Binding source is being set, which is probably why you aren't seeing that change.